# Display JSON data from controller by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the data:

[image]

I have tried this code :

```
 var listUrl = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "Home/TodayFocusListEach?clickID=45";

 $.getJSON(listUrl, function (fList) {
     $.each(fList.ja, function (fIndex, Fdata) {
        $parent.append(Fdata.ID + "<br/>");
     });
 });
```

But the result is undefined.

Could any one tell me how could I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `$.each()` on `fList` instead of `fList.ja`? Rather than a blurry picture from your debugger, can you provide the output from a `console.log(fList)` inserted just before the `$.each()`?

Comment: Thanks , It works well when I used `fList` instead of `fList.ja`.